# Iterating through variables that already have an index and writing to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, iteration

I'm using Selenium WebDriver, but my actual question is more to do with iterating in Python. I have 5 windows open and I'm writing some data from some sites that I have scraped to a number of JSON files that have been created. My code is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(driver.window_handles)):
    try:
        if value != "name" and variable.is_displayed():
            with open("game%s.json" % (i + 1), "w") as outfile:
                json.dump({"some variable": "data", "2nd variable":"2nd data", "nth variable": "nthdata[2][i]"}, outfile)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("text")
```

This works fine when there are no other indexes involved and i've been using iterating a lot, however when it comes to something like the nth variable, where I need the item from the variable i'm using at [2], for example and want that repeated for every window I have and written into the appropriate JSON file, i'm getting an error

`IndexError: string index out of range`

I hope i've made it clear enough what it is I'm trying to achieve, I searched around a bit but can't find what i'm looking for. How could I change this so that the iteration works, the correct amount of times for the exact index I'm trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

If your array have 5 objects len return 5, but the last index of the array is 4. add -1 after the len method to have range beetwen 0 and 4 = 5 objects

```
for i in range(len(driver.window_handles)-1):
    try:
        if value != "name" and variable.is_displayed():
            with open("game%s.json" % (i + 1), "w") as outfile:
                json.dump({"some variable": "data", "2nd variable":"2nd data", "nth variable": "nthdata[2][i]"}, outfile)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("text")
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it doesn't solve the problem i'm having. If I took your suggestion, it doesn't solve the range error, which is specifically with the writing to the JSON file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edit the code in the answer, you forgot a quote in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Yes I solved the problem now thanks, I'll explain tomorrow what I did.

Comment: Ok, if the problem was solved with my solution, please give the points